# Is there a difference between PC4-21333 and PC4-21000 RAM for iMac 5K 27' 2019

Tags: imac, memory

I am trying to upgrade my iMac 2019 5K 27' to 64GB.

Per [Apple specs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201191#27inch2019), the RAM should be PC4-21333, but the only one I seem to be able to find on Amazon or macsales.com seems to be PC4-21000.

Is there an [actual difference](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-ram-to-order-with-the-new-2019-imac.2174176/page-2#post-27230328), or is it just a [rounding choice](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-ram-to-order-with-the-new-2019-imac.2174176/page-2#post-27230350)?

Comment: Is this about what kind of RAM you need, what kind of RAM Amazon has in stock, where to get PC4-21333 RAM, or something else. Please also have a look at [help/on-topic], some of these possible questions are probably off-topic.

Comment: reworded to make it clearer, thanks

Comment: I've removed the secondary question as questions asking to recommend or find a Mac, book, tool, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Ask Different

Answer (score 2):

Crucial.com shows it being PC4-21300 so I would ignore Amazon.

See https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/imac-%28retina-5k%2C-27-inch-3*0ghz-intel-core-i5%2C-2019%29#MEMORYFilters

Comment: in the link you provided it shows it being PC4-21000, unless I am mission something obvious

Comment: From what I read its PC4-21300 DDR4 2666

Comment: Exactly. But I am looking for PC4-21333. Are you saying that PC4-21300 DDR4 2666 is indeed PC4-21333?

Comment: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/what-ram-to-order-with-the-new-2019-imac.2174176/page-2. Apparently 21333 is something that apple has come up with.  While 21300 is not the same it is compatible.  It may be some time before the RAM manufacturers catch up with Apple.

Comment: This is the same comment I linked in my question, but there are two conflicting claims in the answers

Comment: PC4-21000 is not the same as 21333 but 21300 is as close as manufacturers are selling at the moment.  The speed difference is minuscule but it may be an issue if you want to use both the apple ram with the new ram.  Replace it all and you will be good.  It would be interesting to see the RAM that is in your Mac and if it says 21300 or 21333.

Comment: I looked on it, but there were no specs. in the system report only says DDR4 as type and 2667 MHz for speed

Comment: Well meto... once again Apple has the world up in arms.  Was there a part number on the RAM to google?  I have to say I am really curious what the specs are on the RAM that's already in there.  Could answer a lot of questions.

Comment: I felt they there was no useful info but I can look into that again and see if there is anything googlable

Comment: Please do.  I am dying to see if Apple is actually producing RAM that no one (not even crucial) sells.  Some how the answer seem like no.  If someone was mass producing it they'd sell it.  But it is Apple, it wouldn't be a first.